# What is going on in the following python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to process this code in my mind and get the output. I have been getting 1 as the answer which is not true. Can someone explain why?

```
def testString(aString):
  aDict = {}
 for letter in aString:
     num = aString.count(letter)
     if num not in aDict:
         aDict[num] = letter
     else:
         return num
 return -1


text = 'eager'
print(testString(text))
```

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: You need to fix your indentation

Comment: I expect -1 as the output. That is the right answer in the back of the practice test

Comment: I've gone through the iterations manually and posted the answer. It is definitely 1 assuming the indention was corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I've formatted your code:

```
def testString(aString):
    aDict = {}
    for letter in aString:
        num = aString.count(letter)
        if num not in aDict:
            aDict[num] = letter
        else:
            return num
    return -1


text = 'eager'
print(testString(text))
```

Each iteration of the loop:

```
# First iteration
aDict = {}
letter = 'e'
num = 2
if 2 not in aDict: #True
    aDict[2] = 'e'
else:
    return 2

# Second iteration
aDict = {2: 'e'}
letter = 'a'
num = 1
if 1 not in aDict: #True
    aDict[1] = 'a'
else:
    return 1

# Third iteration
aDict = {2: 'e', 1: 'a'}
letter = 'g'
num = 1
if 1 not in aDict: #False
    aDict[1] = 'g'
else:
    return 1 #returns 1
```

Comment: I tried running the code on the computer and output was -1. I don't get why. I also thought that it is 1. But the answer is -1. Which I don't get why.

Comment: Your indentation is probably wrong. Check that `return -1` is not inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing `e` and `a`, `aDict` is `{2: 'e', 1: 'a'}`.  When looking at `g`, `num` is again `1`, which is already a key in `aDict`, so `1` is returned.

Comment: I tried running the code on the computer and output was -1. I don't get why. I also thought that it is 1. But the answer is -1. Which I don't get why.

Comment: You said originally you got 1 with 'eager' as input, and I got 1, so if you now get something different, you must have changed the code or input or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the easiest code snippet to explain in words. This function effectively keeps track of how many times a letter appears, and as soon as it detects a second letter appearing the same amount of times as a previous one, it returns the number of apperances for that letter.

Since in this example 'e' appears twice, 'a' appears once and 'g' also appears once the code terminates here and will return '1'